# Creating a test which runs in a loop

Tags: javascript, typescript, automated-tests, nightwatch.js

I have this code and runs ok but I want it to run in a loop so it will count how many elements it has in the `class="socal"` and then test each link.

```
module.exports = {
    'Unitel Fitness - click' : function (browser) {
    browser
        .url('http://m.unitel.ao/fit/')
        .execute('scrollIntoView(alignToBottom)')
        .waitForElementVisible('.socal>span:nth-child(1) a', 6000)

        .moveToElement('.socal>span:nth-child(1) a', 3, 3)
        .pause(6000)
        .click(".socal>span:nth-child(1) a")
        .pause(6000)
        .keys(['\uE006'])

        .window_handles(function (result) {
            var handle = result.value[1];
            browser.switchWindow(handle);
            browser.pause(1000);
            //browser.assert.urlContains('facebook');
            browser.closeWindow();
        })
        .end();
    }
};
```

I upgraded the code for this but still not doing exactly what I want.
The result is the follwing: (i tried already giving more time)

Number of links: 4 i val before execute: 1 i val before execute: 2 i val before execute: 3 i val before execute: 4  ? Timed out while waiting for element <.socal>span:nth-child("+ i +") a> to be present for 8000 milliseconds.  - expected "visible" but got: not found

```
module.exports = {
                'Social links' : function (browser) {
        browser
            .url('http://m.unitel.ao/fit/')
            .execute(function(){
                        return document.querySelectorAll(".socal>span").length;
                    },

            function(links) {
                total_links = links.value;

                console.log("Number of links: " + total_links);

                for (var i = 1; i <= total_links; i++) {
                    console.log("i val before execute: " + i);

                    browser.execute('scrollIntoView(alignToBottom)');
                    //browser.waitForElementVisible('.socal>span:nth-child("+ i +") a', 8000);

                    //call back function
                    browser.waitForElementVisible('.socal>span:nth-child("+ i +") a', 5000, function() {

                    browser.moveToElement('.socal>span:nth-child("+ i +") a', 3, 3);
                    browser.pause(8000);
                    browser.click(".socal>span:nth-child("+ i +") a");
                    browser.pause(6000);
                    browser.keys(['\uE006']);

                    browser.window_handles(function (result) {
                        var handle = result.value[1];
                        browser.switchWindow(handle);
                        browser.pause(8000);
                        //browser.assert.urlContains('facebook');
                        browser.closeWindow();
                    })
                        });
                }
            })

               // .end();
            }
};
```

Comment: Hi Aaron, i tried to put a for loop, such as, for(var i=0; i<=socal.length;i++)

Comment: Thanks Rita. I don't know typescript so I won't be able to answer your question, however I can tell this is probably a beginner question. As such, I would recommend you to edit what you tried in your answer. Otherwise, people able to answer your question might be reluctant to do so if you don't show you've tried. (the reasoning behind this is that you should first learn to use the language, and if you're given answer to every little problem you're having without having to research it beforehand, you might never learn it properly)

Comment: @Aaron, valid JavaScript is valid TypeScript, so you might be able to help. I don't know anything about nightwatch.js, so I'm bailing ;)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan at first I was thinking about giving a solution based on `document.getElementsByClassName("socal")[0].childNodes.filter(el=> el.tagName == "span").length` but I had no idea where that would fit here, and even if it worked I guess it would be largely suboptimal, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Aaron, I have no idea; that's why I said you "might" be able to help :). I find that people who know JavaScript are sometimes intimidated by TypeScript when they don't need to be. No biggie.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I don't know how I missed the part where you said you didn't know either... well, thanks for encouraging me to answer typescript questions anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Why loop when you can get a collection and use `.length`? It's more performant, too.

```
client.getEls(classSel, function(collection) {      
            return collection.length;
});
```

Comment: Hi QualiT, I tried your suggestion but it tells me back that "getEls is not a function"